# Unwanted extra height to image container element

Tags: html, css

how to get rid of extra height of container element?
See blue stripe below the first picture in the sample code

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-8ryRirhRs5o/VEOv3vaXt7I/AAAAAAAAKSU/xBB9lnkn35Y/s144/BGDragonNGlare.jpg">

</div>

<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-8ryRirhRs5o/VEOv3vaXt7I/AAAAAAAAKSU/xBB9lnkn35Y/s144/BGDragonNGlare.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to the `img`.

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
div img{
  display: block;  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-8ryRirhRs5o/VEOv3vaXt7I/AAAAAAAAKSU/xBB9lnkn35Y/s144/BGDragonNGlare.jpg">

</div>

<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-8ryRirhRs5o/VEOv3vaXt7I/AAAAAAAAKSU/xBB9lnkn35Y/s144/BGDragonNGlare.jpg">
```